# Find all real solutions for $x$ in $ 2(2^x- 1) x^2 + (2^{x^2}-2)x = 2^{x+1} -2 . $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation, exponential-function, roots

Find all real solutions for $x$ in
$$ 2(2^x- 1) x^2 + (2^{x^2}-2)x = 2^{x+1} -2 . $$

I noticed that $$2(2^x- 1) x^2 + (2^{x^2}-2)x = 2^{x+1} -2=2(2^x−1)(x^2-1)+(2^{x^2}−2)x=0.$$

I know that $2^{n+1}-1$ will always be greater than $2^n-1$ for all positive integers. $2^{n-1}-1$ will always be less than $2^n-1$.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1$, $-1$ and $0$ are roots.

Let $x\notin\{0,1,-1\}$.

Thus, $$2(2^x-1)x^2+2x(2^{x^2-1}-1)=2(2^x-1)$$ or
$$(2^x-1)(x^2-1)+(2^{x^2-1}-1)x=0$$ or
$$\frac{2^x-1}{x}+\frac{2^{x^2-1}-1}{x^2-1}=0,$$ which has no real roots because for any $a\neq0$ we have $$\frac{2^a-1}{a}>0.$$

Comment: How did you get it to that form?

Comment: @Bongocat I added something. See now.

Comment: Isn't this kind've working backwords. Our first step was to assume that $x$ was not defined on the set ${0, 1, -1}.$

Comment: @Bongocat The first step was to understand that $1$, $-1$ and $0$ are roots. See please the first line of my solution.

Comment: How do we immediately know that $-1, 0$, and $1$ are the roots?

Comment: @Bongocat I just substituted it. Check it! For example, for $x=0$ we obtain: $0+0=2^{0+1}-2,$ which is true.

Comment: Wouldn't substituting not be a rigorous enough proof?

Comment: @Bongocat I used a definition of the root of the equation.  By the definition $1$, $-1$ and $0$ are roots and we proved that our equation has no another real roots. So we solved this equation. Sorry that I'll give the following example. Let we need to solve the equation $x=2$. We see that $2$ is a root of the equation and we see also, that our equation has no another roots. Thus, we solved this equation and got the answer: $\{2\}$.

Comment: I think I understand most-almost everything. I don't understand the statement $x\neq\{0,1,-1\}$ quite well. Isn't this a contradiction? We said the roots are $-1, 0, 1.$ Now we say that $x$ doesn't belong to this set?

Comment: @Bongocat  It's not a contradiction. We tried to find roots $x$ such that $x\notin\{1,-1,0\}$, but without success, as you saw.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you for the step-by-step walk through!

Comment: @Bongocat You are welcome! Good luck!